# What is the difference between these various spacecraft pyrotechnics?

Tags: terminology, explosives, pyrotechnic-fasteners

The following terms have been used in various Space Exploration StackExchange questions and answers.  **What are the differences (if any) between these various terms?**

- detonating cord
- detonating fuse (as in [mild detonating fuse](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45012/26446))
- [explosive bolt](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53690/26446)
- [frangible nut](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50920/26446)
- igniter
- [initiator](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21776/26446) (as in NASA standard initiator)
- squib